# Proving infimum is the greatest lower bound

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I think I am on the right track with this proof, but I am using a similar technique used by the authors of the book to prove the completeness axiom.

Can I get a proof verification?

Prove

Let $U$ be a set with a total order. If $A \subseteq U$ and $m=inf(A)$ then $m$ is the greatest of all lower bounds of $A$.

Attempt:

Assume $m=inf(A)$ then $m \leq x$, $\forall x \in A$.
Also if $l>m$, $ \exists s \in A$ $\ni s<l$

Let $Lb(A)=\{u \in U :u$ is a lower bound of $A\}$

then $m \in$$Lb(A)=\{u \in U :u$ is a lower bound of $A\}$

State $m=Inf(A)$

Prove if  $y \in A$ then $y \geq m$.

Assume BWOC that $y\in A$ and $y<m$.

$\implies$ $\exists x \in Lb(A) \ni x>y$

But since $x \in Lb(A), x\leq s, \forall s \in A$

Thus $y<x \leq y$ A contradiction

Next Prove if $l>m, \exists s \in A \ni s<l$

This will obstruct $l$(any larger number than m) from being a lower bound

We know if $x>m$ then $x \notin Lb(A)$.

So if $l>m$ then $l \notin Lb(A)$

This means there is an element $s$ in $A$ that prevents this.

So $s \in A$ and $s<l$.

So $m$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$

Comment: I'm confused.  The definition I recall of infimum is that it **is** the greatest lowest bound of a set. That is, if $m = \inf(A)$ then $m$ is outright the greatest lower bound. Is there a different definition you're using or some nuance I'm overlooking?

Comment: So you think that stating the definition will complete the proof?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, yes; but then obviously that would beg the question of why one would need to "prove" this at all. (It would make a very poor textbook exercise, for instance.) Which makes me wonder if there's something in this that I'm overlooking, or that there's some other definition or whatever you're using that I don't know. (After all, definitions can absolutely vary depending on who you ask.) I guess the most relevant bit of information you can give us, if my definition is the same as yours anyhow, is where this problem came from?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer The question was assume $m$ is the infimum and prove it is the greatest lower bound

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Also this is the question that the book states

Comment: What is the book's definition of infimum? Hundreds of years ago, European scholars usually wrote in Latin because they all learned it in school. And the definition of infimum was exactly "greatest lower bound". And this is still the standard definition of infimum, in any language.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet if $m=inf(A)$ then $m \leq x$, $\forall x \in A$.
Also if $l>m$, $ \exists s \in A$ $\ni s<l$

Comment: $\forall x\in A\,(m\le x)$ says that m is a lower bound for $A$. And $\forall l>m \,\exists x\in A\,(x<l)$ says no $l>m$ is a lower bound for $A$.  Observe that if $S$ is a set with the property that $m\in S \subset  \{y:y\le m\}$ then $m$ is the greatest member of $S.$  Therefore if $\inf(A)=m$ exists then the set of lower bounds of $A$ has that property.